# What's meaning of "into" in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

He was shocked **into** a confession of guilt.

What's the meaning of **into** in this sentence?

Comment: to be shocked into a state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to find an analysis of **talk someone into** [doing something}. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/talk%20into#:%7E:text=%3A%20to%20get%20(someone)%20to,us%20into%20buying%20the%20car.) has:

> *talk into* [phrasal verb] [[multi-word verb; EA]]
>
> : to get (someone) to do something by talking about the good reasons
> for doing it: to convince or persuade (someone) to do something
>
> - *The salesman talked us into buying the car.*

To *shock someone into* [doing  something] follows the same pattern, with the meaning to get someone to do something as a knee-jerk reaction. 'Into' is here analysed as a particle licensing an action or state ('[into] buying a car', '[into] [having] a nervous breakdown'), ususally followed by an ing-clause. But the verb may sometimes be omitted with say 'making', 'committing', 'having' [eg a nervous breakdown] when clarity isn't compromised:

- He was shocked into [making] a confession of guilt.

Other nearby expressions are

- *to scare someone into doing something* [[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scare-into-doing)] and
- *to trick someone into doing something* [[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/trick+someone+into)]

Comment: Can i rewrite it as - he was persuaded to confess his guilt by shocking him.                                                Similarly i can rewrite (The salesman talked us into buying the car.)-The salesman persuaded us  to buy the car by talking to us.

Comment: These are idioms. Your first suggestion sounds very unnatural, and the second not too idiomatic.

Comment: But can i understand in this way.

Comment: I think 'persuaded' is not forceful enough to echo 'shock someone into'.  And 'The salesman persuaded us to buy the car' doesn't really accept 'by talking to us': it's unlikely he used any other method of communication. It's best to get familiar with how the idioms are used.

Comment: But Cambridge dictionary give the definition you mentioned like this..

Comment: Oxford dictionary give the definition, as per the definition(I can say):- The salesman talked us into buying the car=The sales man talked us in order to make us buy the car.Is it correct now?

Comment: The 'shock' could have been an unexpected incident which made the guilty person feel he had to confess, not necessarily a way of 'persuading' him.

Comment: *Shocked* does not necessarily mean electric torture here. The context will tell. *Into* shows the direction was to go *inside* (the situation or result). Otherwise: shocked *out of* the idea that he should sing in public.